# compare size between windows to linux

Tags: linux

I have an ISO file with size 5457888KB on windows.

I want to transfer this iso file to my Linux machine.

How to compare the checksum in Linux machine (which command return size file on linux as windows) in order verify if the transfer (ftp) succeeded ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which command return size file on linux as windows

There are some ways to check the file size on Linux:

```
$ stat -c %s <file_name> (in bytes)
$ du -sk <file_name> (in kilobytes)
```

but you shouldn't based on that to verify the integrity.

You'd better generate checksum of the ISO file on the Windows with some tools like: [WinMD5Sum](http://www.nullriver.com/products/winmd5sum), [md5sums](http://www.pc-tools.net/win32/md5sums/), ... and compare on Linux by executing the following command:

```
$ echo "<md5sum_value><space><space><file_name>" | md5sum -c
```

PS: you may also want to take a look at [mod_digest](http://www.smartftp.com/oss/proftpd/) if you're using ProFTPD.

Answer (score 0):

You can use du (disk usage ) for this :

```
du -h /home/user1
```

-h

--human-readable

> Append a size letter to each size, such as ‘M’ for mebibytes. Powers
>   of 1024 are used, not 1000; ‘M’ stands for 1,048,576 bytes. This
>   option is equivalent to --block-size=human-readable. Use the --si
>   option if you prefer powers of 1000.